# How to count how many letters are inside a string?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a code that will count how many letters are in a string. For some reason
every time when I enter my message it show multiple letters that are the same. Is there anyway to prevent this? I also want to show the result using the alphabetical order. Capital and lowercase letters will count as one.

```
first = (input('Enter the first message: '))
second = (input('Enter the second message: '))
third = (input('Enter the third message: '))
message = first + second + third
print(message)
for i in message:
    counter = message.count(i)
    print(i, ':', counter)
```

Comment: if you want to treat upper and lower the same, make them all lower(). if you want unique counts, use a set and only count over the set() of your input. if you want them alphabetically, sort them. To ALL of these problems there are related questions and answers on this site, search it, use it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a `collections.Counter` on an `upper`cased version of the string, and then `sort`ing its `items`:

```
>>> message = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter(filter(str.isalpha, message.upper()))
>>> for letter, count in sorted(counts.items()):
...     print(f"{letter}: {count}")
...
A: 1
B: 1
C: 1
D: 1
E: 3
F: 1
G: 1
H: 2
I: 1
J: 1
K: 1
L: 1
M: 1
N: 1
O: 4
P: 1
Q: 1
R: 2
S: 1
T: 2
U: 2
V: 1
W: 1
X: 1
Y: 1
Z: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using dict comprehension and count():

```
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."

text = text.upper()
data = {char: text.count(char) for char in sorted(set(text)) if char.isalpha()}
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
{'A': 7, 'B': 1, 'C': 4, 'D': 8, 'E': 11, 'G': 2, 'I': 11, 'L': 6, 'M': 6, 'N': 5, 'O': 10, 'P': 3, 'Q': 1, 'R': 6, 'S': 6, 'T': 9, 'U': 6}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code for displaying the letter with count number :**

```
first = (input('Enter the first message: '))
second = (input('Enter the second message: '))
third = (input('Enter the third message: '))
message = first + second + third
print(message)

unique=''.join(set(message.lower()))
a={}
for i in unique:
    counter = message.count(i)
    a[i]=counter
    
sort=sorted(a.items())

print('\n'. join(str(x) for x in sort))
```

**Output:**

```
Enter the first message: hey
Enter the second message: Hi
Enter the third message: Hello
heyHiHello
('e', 2)
('h', 1)
('i', 1)
('l', 2)
('o', 1)
('y', 1)
```

**Try this code for only letters**

```
first = (input('Enter the first message: '))
second = (input('Enter the second message: '))
third = (input('Enter the third message: '))
message = first + second + third
print(message)

unique=''.join(set(message.upper()))

#sorted function is used to sort the letters
sort=sorted(unique)

print(' '. join(str(x) for x in sort))
```

**Output**

```
Enter the first message: Hey
Enter the second message: Hi
Enter the third message: hellO
HeyHihellO
E H I L O Y
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you this is what i need. May I ask how to print only letters, not numbers or symbols?

Comment: If you want to print only letters then you can try the second code